# Stuck with main method with hibernate usage

Tags: java, hibernate

Need your insight, look forward to your succor.

This is the main method, trying to persist data into db with hibernate.

```
package com.hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.dto.Employee;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        System.out.println("abc");

        emp.setFirstName("John");
        emp.setLastName("More");
        emp.setSalary(999999972);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(emp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();

    }

}
```

This is the model class, viz. Employee

```
    package com.hibernate.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
       private int id;
       private String firstName; 
       private String lastName;   
       private int salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }  

}
```

Here's hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">***</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.dto.Employee"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Jars which I've included listed as:

```
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\antlr-2.7.7.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\classmate-1.3.0.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\required\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\jpa\hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar
 D:\hibernate-release-5.1.0.Final\lib\java8\hibernate-java8-5.1.0.Final.jar
 C:\Users\arpit_pipersaniya\Downloads\javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
 C:\Users\arpit_pipersaniya\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar
```

When I run this java application, nothing happens and hence no desired result.

Comment: is `abc` being printed?

Comment: where is  `@table(name="table_name")` in your model class?

Comment: @subburoyal @table(name="table_name") is not required, can you add you log console ??

Comment: No this is not the JPA API. Removing JPA tag!

Comment: Thanks all!
But 'abc' is not being printed.
Jpa Tag works, even if you add or not; here principal concern is main method is not working.

Comment: @ArpitPipersaniya He means the `jpa` tag of your question.

Comment: if "abc" doesn't show up, this means that you are executing the wrong class maybe ... just edit your question and add you log please

Comment: After adding below statements to hibernate config file, it's working  now:
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
        PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


Thanks a lot guys, for your time!

Comment: To be precise, this is how my config. file look like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By tweaking configuration file, now it works file without any glitch.

This is how hibernate.cfg.xml looks like, now:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
        PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

*<!-- <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> -->*

  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root2</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.hibernate.dto.Employee"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```